# Add text to random string

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, iframe

if text starts with `http://vk.com` then add

```
<iframe src="
```

at end
 and `" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>` at the end

All the `http://vk.com/random$$` are in the database..
and the link is always random..

Example:

```
http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=187139107&id=163792624&hash=15cbcf3a3c503bd8
```

To

```
<iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=187139107&id=163792624&hash=15cbcf3a3c503bd8" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Keep in mind, that after "video_ext.php?" its always random.

So.. here is the script which could take care of that:

```
        <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "admin_user", "yarak", "admin_name");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if( $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM parts") )
{
    $i = 0;
    $done = array();
    while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
    {
        $link = unserialize( $row['part_content'] );
        $link = $link[0];
        if( preg_match( '#http://vk\.com/video_ext\.php\?oid=(.*?)#', $link ) )
        {
            $i = $i+1;
            echo 'Original Link: ' . htmlentities( $link );
            $link = preg_replace( '#http://vk\.com/video_ext\.php\?oid=(.*?)#', '<iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=$1" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>', $link );
            $_link = serialize( array( $link ) );
            echo '<br />Part ID: ' . $row['part_id'] . '<br />New Link: '. htmlentities( $link ) . '<br /><br />';

            if( $row['part_id'] AND !in_array( $row['part_id'], $done ) )
            {
                $done[] = $row['part_id'];
                $mysqli->query( 'UPDATE `parts` SET `part_content` = \''.$_link.'\' WHERE `part_id`=\''.$row['part_id'].'\'' );
            }
        }
    }

    echo '<br />Count: ' . $i . '<br />Link conversion Completed.';
}
else
{
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Here is what i get:

```
Original Link: <iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=THEIMPORTANTPART" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
Part ID: 13489
New Link: <iframe src="<iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>THEIMPORTANTPART" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I don't know what the problem is -.-

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($link)` to see if it contains what you think it should. if the preg_match fails, then nothing happens...

Comment: I swear I saw this question earlier today.

Comment: where? Maybe the same question :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "admin_e1", "sure", "admin_main");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if( $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM parts") )
{
  $i = 0;
  $done = array();
  while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
  {
    $link = unserialize( $row['part_content'] );
    $link = $link[0];
    if (strpos($text, 'http://vk.com') === 0)
    {
      $i = $i+1;
      echo 'Original Link: ' . htmlentities( $link );
      $link = '<iframe src="' . $link . '" width="100%" height="450px" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
      $_link = serialize( array( $link ) );
      echo '<br />Part ID: ' . $row['part_id'] . '<br />New Link: '. htmlentities( $link ) . '<br /><br />';

      if( $row['part_id'] AND !in_array( $row['part_id'], $done ) )
      {
        $done[] = $row['part_id'];
        $mysqli->query( 'UPDATE `parts` SET `part_content` = \''.$_link.'\' WHERE `part_id`=\''.$row['part_id'].'\'' );
      }
    }
  }

  echo '<br />Count: ' . $i . '<br />Link conversion Completed.';
}
else
{
  echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: @blex please check my new snippet.

Comment: That looks more like it! I can't test it right now, but I'll surely upvote it if it solves OP's problem.

Comment: @Nou4r I need more details, what exactly is goes wrong?

Comment: There are no errors, and the "counter" isn't working.

Comment: Also fix your mysqli query to use parameters or mysqli->escape_string

Comment: The links didn't change either, and i didn't got an "sucess" nor a "error" message.

Comment: Thanks to your help, i modified my source with some codes of "your" source, and now my streams are back up! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your preg_match pattern needs to escape the regex special characters. The pattern should look like:

```
preg_match( '#http://vk\.com/video_ext\.php\?oid=(.*?)#', $link )
```

And similar in preg_replace.

Comment: @Nou4r Additionnally to this, try commenting that line: `$link = $link[0];`

Comment: The problem is, the new link is always blank... http://i.imgur.com/bX1J7Du.png I seriously don't know what the problem is o.0

Comment: @Nou4r Have a look at [**this stripped down version**](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=mKfTB91X) and try it as it is, to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Yes, it does what i want.. but i don't know the urls.. there are 5k+ urls stored in my database which are always random after "oid=". But yeah the script did what i want besides you needed to write the full urls.

Comment: Thank you alot for your help, its fixed now. Thanks